# Getting an Unassignable Type on one component but not the other and they look similar to me. I can't figure out what is different

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to both Typescript and React. I have an app with two operational Components in it, one for Scanning QR Codes (Scan) and one for Generating QR Codes (Generate). I am trying to pass runtime options into the operational Components. Each operational component has a different set of run time options. I am trying to pass them through props. The code for the Generate component seems to be acceptable to Typescript but the code for the Scan is preventing the build and won't compile. As far as I can tell the code is similar and I can see no reason the Generate is acceptable and Scan is not. Nothing I have researched seems close enough to give me the answer I need.

To clarify, I am exporting the props in these components to the components in dha-qrcode.

I am including screenshots of the code:

Generate:

[image: Generate Component code block]

Scan:

[image: Scan Component code block]

Error Message:

[image: Error Message from Scan code block]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you're trying to do.

Your `IProps` in both `Generator` and `Scanner` are the props for *your* components, not the imported components from `dha-qrcode`.

For example,

```
<Scan options={{ showViewFinder: true, delay: 500, ... }} />
```

however, you're not using your `Scan`, you're using `Scan` (aliased to `Scanner`) from `dha-qrcode`. You need to be providing props that match *its* prop interface.

`<Scanner showViewFinder={true} ... />`

It doesn't seem like it supports all the props that you are assuming it does.

Comment: Actually I am trying to export the props to dha-code. I wasn't clear about that. dha-qrcode has an npm module for the scan and a different one for the generate. The interesting thing is they both work well without even passing the options. But the team wants the options under control of the developer (not user) who writes the wrapper. Just trying to comply. Thanks for the tip Tyler. I will look deeper at the modules on github and see if I get a clue there.

Comment: You don't export props, you pass props.